# Proving $\lim f(x_n)=+\infty $ implies $\lim x_n = +\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Here's what I have to show:

> Suppose that $f:[0,\infty )\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and that
>    $(x_n)$ is a sequence in $[0,\infty )$ such that $\lim f(x_n)=+\infty
>  $. Prove that $\lim x_n = +\infty$.

Here's my attempt:

Suppose that $(x_n)$ does not coverge to $+\infty $. Then there exists a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ of $(x_n)$ which is (strictly) bounded above by some $M>0$. Thus, $x_{n_k} \in [0, M)$ for every $k\in \mathbb{N}$. By Bolzano Weierstrass Theorem, there exists a subsequence $(x_{n_{k^{\prime}}})$ of $(x_{n_k})$ converging to some $c\in [0,M]$. Now since $f$ is continuous on $[0,M]$, we have $\lim f(x_{n_{k^{\prime}}})=f(c)$. However, since $(f((x_{n_{k^{\prime}}}))$ is a subsequence of $(f(x_n))$, we also should have $\lim f(x_{n_{k^{\prime}}})=+\infty$. A contradiction!

Is my proof correct? My proof looks extremely clumsy. Perhaps I was wondering if we could prove it directly.

Comment: Small notational note: $(x_{n_{k'}})$ doesn't particularly make sense. Is it shorthand for $(x_{n_{k'}})_{k'=1}^\infty$? Because that is identical to the sequence $(x_{n_k})_{k=1}^\infty$. You could denote the sub-subsequence by $(x_{n'_k})$, but this isn't suggestive that it is a subsequence of $(x_{n_k})$, only of $(x_n)$. Or you could go to triple subscripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct, but you don't need to use the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem. Once you know a subsequence of $(x_n)$ is contained in $[0, M]$ for some $M$, you can just say that $f$ is bounded on $[0, M]$ by continuity.

Comment: That's right! Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Bolzano-Weierstrass kinda needs to be there, at least behind the scenes. This reasoning doesn't work without local compactness.

Comment: @TheoBendit That's true. You can't prove continuous functions are bounded on closed intervals without using compacity.